# Filter a dropdown based on the content of another dropdown in PowerApps

Tags: dropdown, powerapps

I need to filter a dropdown list from the results of another dropdown list above it.  I'm filtering personnel based on their respective agency, so when the user selects their Agency from the first dropdown list, the second dropdown list is only populated with Personnel from that Agency.

Agency and Personnel are two separate entities (tables) in the common data service (CDS).

So far I can get the list of Agencies from the CDS with

`Filter(Agency, AgencyType = 9)`

where [9] = the type of agency I'm filtering for.

I just can't get the list of people assigned to that agency to populate.  I have tried:

`ITEM: Filter(Personnel, ddAgency.Selected.Value in Personnel.AgencyID)`
where ddAgency is the name of the referenced dropdown.

I am getting a single table error from PowerApps, so I guess it's my syntax.  I'm trying to filter data and draw results based on values in 2 entities (tables).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something along the lines of

```
ddPersonnel.Items: Filter(Personnel, AgencyID = ddAgency.Selected.Value)
```

The expression used to filter the data source already assumes that you are in the context of the data source being filtered, so you don't need to specify `Personnel.AgencyID` - `AgencyID` is enough.

The expression on the right of the equality sign (`ddAgency.Selected.Value`) may need to be updated, if the column that has the agency id is not called `Value`. For example, if it's called `Id`, the expression would be the one below.

```
ddPersonnel.Items: Filter(Personnel, AgencyID = ddAgency.Selected.Id)
```

You can read this as "Filter the data source `Personnel` where the value of the `AgencyID` field is the same as the value of the `Id` of the `Agency` element selected in the dropdown `ddAgency`.

Comment: That seems to be the issue, but there is a problem with the way PowerApps CDS defines the AgencyID.  It is an autonumber field in the Agency table (entity), but the value in the Personnel table (entity) is also a number, but is formatted differently.  The Personnel entity formats the number without leading 0's, but the AgencyID is an autonumber that has default 5 leading zeros.

Comment: Maybe if you format it in a way that unifies the two formats it would work: `Filter(Personnel, Value(AgencyID) = Value(ddAgency.Selected.Id)`

Comment: For Bonus Points, how would you concatenate the `Name` and `Lastname` fields in the dropdown?

`Filter(Search(Personnel.CONCATENATE(Name," ",Lastname)), AgencyID=ddAgency.Selected.PrimaryId)`

doesn't work.

Comment: @Matteo I'm 6 years late, but `&` concatenates in Power Apps. So it would be `Personnel(Name & Lastname)` for that section of the query, assuming it works, otherwise.